# Calculate the array name PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large number of arrays

- arrawithvalues0
- arrawithvalues1
- arrawithvalues2
- arrawithvalues3
- ......
- arrawithvalues999

Therefore I would like to calculate the name of the array to use in my script
I am using this code:

```
$secondarray = array();
for($iii = 0; $iii < 1000; ++ $iii) {   
    $array3 = "arrawithvalues" . $iii;      
    for($II = 0; $II < 10; ++ $II) {
        array_push ( $secondarray, $$array3[$II]);  
    }
}
```

But get errors like this

- Notice: Undefined variable: a in xxxxxxxxx  on line xx
- Notice: Undefined variable: r in xxxxxxxxx  on line xx
- Notice: Undefined variable: r in xxxxxxxxx  on line xx

Thanks for reading and help

Comment: don't use `$$`!!!! it's very poor style. and calling the loop variables `$iii` and `$II` is hardly better.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a top level 1000-item array rather than 1000 quasi-identical variables?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use braces, like this:

```
    array_push ( $secondarray, {$$array3}[$II]);
```

Right now, your code is being interpreted as this:

```
    array_push ( $secondarray, ${$array3[$II]});
```

which is why you are getting those errors.